# Button in kv file doesn't redirect to the desired page

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hi I'm having a problem with my code: as you read in the title I have this button which should redirect the user to another page, but when clicked it doesn't do anything. Can you help me?

Here is the code

Here I define the button

```
<Home>:
    name: "home"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .7, 1

        Label:
            text: "Home"
            font_size: 50

        Label:
            text: ""

        Button:
            text: "FAQ"
            on_release:
                app.root.current: "FAQ_AP"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Label:
            text: ""

        Button:
            text: "Gestionale"
            on_release:

        Label:
            text: ""
```

And here I create the page in which the button should redirect:

```
<FAQ_AP>:
    name: "FAQ_AP"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .7, 1

        Label:
            font_size: 50
            text: "Sei un'azienda o un privato?"

        Label:
            text: ""

        Label:
            text: ""

        Button:
            text: "Azenda"
            on_release:

        Label:
            text: ""

        Button:
            text: "Privato"
            on_release:

        Label:
            text: ""
```

If you could help me it would be the best. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing `app.root.current: "FAQ_AP"` with **`app.root.current = "FAQ_AP"`**.

Comment: I had already figured it out some time ago, but thank you anyways for your avaliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mention `.app` in the `on_release` functionality of the button.

Use this, it works fine

```
Button:
    text: "FAQ"
    on_release:
        root.manager.current = "FAQ_AP"
        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```